# Can I update Clash of Clans downloaded with an old Apple ID using a new Apple ID?

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-id, clash-of-clans

A new update in Clash of Clans has been arrived and it is asking me the password through which I downloaded this game but I don't know the password. How can I update it with my new Apple ID?

Answer (score 1):

App updates must be done with the Apple ID that was used to originally download the app. If you wish to use another Apple ID with an app you need to delete the app and download it again from the App Store using the new Apple ID.

Comment: But will it delete my clash of clans village plz tell..

Comment: @Abuzar Clash of Clans villages are stored in Game Center, so providing your Game Center account is not changed the village will remain

Comment: No but my village in this new account is a secondary one .so it doesn't ask to open my account it will automatically open my cousins account which is the first village made on this account..

Comment: @Abuzar What do you mean by 'secondary'? When you launch the game it should ask which village you would like to open…

Comment: Yes it asks to open my cuzins account as he uses the same apple i.d

Comment: @Abuzar Not exactly sure what you mean — when it asks which village to open, select yours. The villages are stored in Game Center, so it doesn't matter what Apple ID downloaded the app.

Comment: It only asked to open my cuzins not mine bro

Comment: So wat should i do now

Comment: @Abuzar I don't know — wait for someone else to see this question, someone else may know the answer. Either way, please stop posting 'help' comments — they don't 'bump' the question. For attracting attention to a question, see the [bounty system](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties).